# Renderflex overflow caused by row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to implement simple one-two line text.
Text will have a starting text then icon and ending text.Due to different styles i am using row with text,icon and text widgets.
I am getting `A RenderFlex overflowed by 16 pixels on the right.` error.
i enclose the row in flexible and expanded but still not working. i just want the text to drop at the end of line to next line.

```
Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        left: 20,
        right: 20,
      ),
      width: mdq.size.width,
      child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(


              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Tap ',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.add),
                  Text(
                    'on the right hand corner to start a new chat.',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 15,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'You can communicate with the user who have installed Just Meetups and Deals app',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 15,
              ),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Text(
                  'Start communicating',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),

    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Expanded` widget

```
Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        left: 20,
        right: 20,
      ),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Tap ',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.add),
                  Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    'on the right hand corner to start a new chat.',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17,
                    ),
                  ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 15,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'You can communicate with the user who have installed Just Meetups and Deals app',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 15,
              ),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Text(
                  'Start communicating',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),

    ),
```

[Here's a codepen of it working](https://codepen.io/FirasDev/pen/jObXqKR)

Comment: as i mentioned that i tried expanded but its not working.  I am updating widget tree

Comment: @BilalRabbi i have update my answer, check if that's what you need

Comment: Sorry sir not exactly as it has pushed the 2nd child of parent column to the bottom and after + icon the text is not inline with first text.  i was just trying to creating mockup of whatsapp screen when user has not contacted anyone.

Comment: You need to describe your problem more, i thought the problem was your text overflowing, post an image to your op if it helps

Comment: Parent widgets is just a ListView.builder in StreamBuilder  which is in scaffold body

Comment: @BilalRabbi alright updated my reply, check again and the codepen too

Comment: I will accept your answer Thank you so much. There is still one issue the text,icon,text are not in online not sure what can i do with that.

Comment: @BilalRabbi please do a separate post with code and screenshot with a good explanation so that everyone can benefit from your question in the future.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61899181/flutter-text-and-icon-in-one-line-in-row

Answer (score 0):

You need not use any flex like [Expanded, Flexible, etc] for rows in the column because rows default takes max-width available by column

**You are getting an error because your row child width is more than available screen size**

- you can use Expanded for the **children of large width** of rows in Expanded to wrap the child in available width inside a row.