# Flutter - How to show text and icon in one line in row?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using row widget with three child widgets:
Text
Icon
Text

I want all of them to appear in single line same level horizontally  and drop to new line if text increases.

I am using below code for Row widget but last Text widget is not aligned correctly
[image]

The text dropping should start below the "`Tap`" and "`on the right hand`" is not aligned

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Tap ',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 17,
      ),
    ),
    Icon(Icons.add),
    Expanded(
      child: Text(
        'on the right hand corner to start a new chat.',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 17,
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `Text.rich` with `WidgetSpan` to put icon inside text (inline)

```dart
Text.rich(
  TextSpan(
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 17,
    ),
    children: [
      TextSpan(
        text: 'Tap',
      ),
      WidgetSpan(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      TextSpan(
        text: 'on the right hand corner to start a new chat.',
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need put sinlein line **crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start** inside
Row

```
Row (
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
                  Icon(Icons.add, size: 14),
                  Expanded(
                      child: Text("your multiline text "),
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
    
)
```